# How to find a specific file in my git repo

Tags: git

Is there any git command to search a file **only** inside a git repo?

I'm trying to find a name called example.php and I would like to know the location of that file in my repo.

Comment: What os are you using? Unix: `find . | grep example.php`

Comment: I know that command, I was just wondering if there's a git command like git grep.

Comment: `git ls-files` is like the swiss army knife of index-aware file selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to grep, you can do the following:

```
git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD | grep example.php
```

This searches through all of the files git is currently tracking for you for example.php.